# Can a app have different files for different devices?

Tags: android

I was looking at the google play store and one of the apps for size said varies with device.  Right now my app has 2 sizes for all its graphic images.  The only way that makes sense to me for the app to vary in size depending on device is for the google play store to have more then one apk file for the same product.  Which does not make sense to me.

Is there a way for my app to have different files for different devices???

Comment: Have you looked at the developer docs? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring specifically to the Google Play store then yes, you can have multiple "active APKs" with different device requirements. This is commonly used to support different minimum Android SDK versions (e.g. have two versions of your app, one for 4.0+ and one for older versions).

This is documented here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Also note that there are other Android stores (e.g. Amazon's Kindle store) which may not support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.You can create different layout, Bitmaps and place it in different drawable folder inside res. Check this Link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html